# how to make ExtJS grid summary feature show above grid header

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs-grid

I know it is possible to use grid's summary plugin and dock it to the bottom or top of the grid (underneath the header part), however I was wondering if it is possible and how would one go about putting the summary right above the grid headers..

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ext?

Comment: ExtJS 6. Sorry for not putting that in the question.

Comment: Not a good way to do it unfortunately, the weight of the docked item is hard coded in the feature init method. You would need to override the entire method and change it.

Answer (score 1):

Evan Trimboli gave the correct hint: You can adjust the weight of the summaryBar. This does not take immediate effect at runtime, so to enforce the new weight being used, you will have to call `moveDocked`:

```
    panel.down('[itemId=summaryBar]').setWeight(99);
    panel.moveDocked(panel.down('[itemId=summaryBar]'), 'top');
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g4c